# How to call project classes for another project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I'm developing a dynamic java web application with eclipse. I have 2 projects.
There are:
1. Test1
2. Main
How to use Test1 classes and libraries in Main project?

I'm trying following: Main Project properties->Java Build Path->Projects and Added Test1. 
Then i'm writing code using Test1 classes. And, When i compile Main project following errors occured:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/test/caller/Req
```

and

```
    Class not found Exception
```

Comment: That is the correct process. Can you clean both the projects and let us know if it still doesnt find the classes?

Comment: Do you use any build tool?  Maven , ant ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a few things to allow your main project to see it.

First: Mark Test1 project as a library. This can be done from project properties.

Second: Allow access to the Test1 classes from the Main project properties.

Third: Include the classes you would like inside the main project, eg:

```
#include Main.class123
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Goto Project --> Build-Path --> Projects --> Add project ( select your project ) --> Ok. Next clean and re-build your projects to make sure that all build paths are configured correctly.